# How to check successfully multiple (two) PreparedStatement execution one by one on a manual commit JDBC connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, transactions, commit

I have two table (`saleitem`, `balance`) that when a customer buys any item, it must be inserted into `saleitem` and subtracted from their `balance`.

So I created a manual commit connection and if all statements are OK, I commit the connection.

The first SQL statement is a simple INSERT for `saleitem`, the second SQL statement is an UPDATE with a condition:

```
UPDATE balance SET amount = amount - ? WHERE walletid = ? AND userid = ? AND amount >= ?;
```

When I had Auto-Commit connection i could to check `preparedStatement.executeUpdate()` is more than `0`.

But this doesn't work when I have manual commit connection.

Now if I insert new sale item into `saleitem` table, and the user doesn't have money in their wallet (in `balance` table), the `saleitem` is inserted but balance is not updated.

If the balance is not enough or `walletid` is not exist , I don't want to do insert and update , but `rollback()` this transaction

How can I check success of persistence for multiple SQL statements, and then commit them when I have manual commit connection?

Comment: *but it's dont worked when i have manual commit connection*: why wouldn't it work? executeUpdate() returns the number of updated rows, whether you use autocommit or not.

Comment: Are you sure that the user has sufficient balance? If not, the update will not affect any rows. Also, it would be good if you shared some more code to make it obvious what you're doing.

Comment: it's just developer mistake when he wants to send wrong data!
i wants to delete this question but i think it's useful for some java developers.
and it's pretty could to checked it by `preparedStatement.executeUpdate()>0` and in final if all Statements are `true` you can to `connection.commit()` them

Comment: You need to show your current code.